# Многострочный не компилируемый текст в атрибутах тега. Pug(Jade)

Tags: jade, pug

Есть такой вод код на jade (pug):

```
body(
  |{% case page.url %}
  | {% when '/' %}
  |    class="hellopage"
  | {% when page.url contains '/gallery/' %}
  |    class="gallerypage"
  |{% endcase %}
  )
```

Все {% .. %}, это Ликвидские штуки, поэтому компилировать Jade их не стоит, для этого используется `|`.
Естественно, такой формат компилятор не понимает (использую gulp-jade). Что можете посоветовать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я бы сделал следующим образом, так и код выглядит почище:

```js
-
  var pageClass = '';
  switch(page.url) {
    case '/': pageClass = 'hellopage'; break;
    case '/gallery/': pageClass = 'gallerypage'; break;
  }  
body(class=pageClass)
```

Вместо `switch` можете использовать и другие условия, как-никак там JS зона

Comment: спустя 6 лет даже проверять это не стану, поверю на слово, что работает))

Comment: А я только сейчас заметил, что вопрос такой старый 